# Formatting the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

I have some data that I want to plot, of mean daily wind speeds for 2013 on Brown Top Mountain. There are a lot of points, so here is a look at the first few rows just to give an idea:

[image: Mean Daily WindSpeed]

I can plot the data and make it look good, except for the x axis. Here is a sample of my code so far:

```
>attach(Brown_Top_2013)
>BT<-ggplot(Brown_Top_2013, aes(TIMESTAMP, Sum.Of.WS_Avg))
> >BT+geom_point(col="royalBlue")+labs(x="Date", y="Mean Wind Speed (m/s)", title= "Daily Mean Wind Speed 2013"+scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(01/03/13, 12/27/13,1))
```

This can get me a decent looking plot, except it does not include any ticks along the x axis, like so:

[image: Mean Daily Wind Speed Plot]

Ultimately I would like to get `ggplot` to show at least one day of each month on the x axis.
Any help would be much appreciated as I have scoured the internet for hours now trying to figure this out. I have a feeling it might have to do with the way the `TIMESTAMP` date is set up, but let me know what you think!

Comment: Maybe you need `scale_x_date` instead of `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `seq(01/03/13, 12/27/13,1)`. It's a single number (0.02564103), which probably isn't in your actual x-range, so there are no breaks, resulting in a lack of x-axis ticks. Probably you intended something like `seq(as.Date("2013-01-03"), as.Date("2013-12-12"), by="1 day")`, although you probably want breaks every week or month, rather than every day. (I'm assuming here that `TIMESTAMP` is formatted as a Date, rather than as character or factor.)

Comment: Also, best to avoid using `attach` in general and it's not necessary when using `ggplot`. The first argument to `ggplot` is the data frame, which makes that data frame's columns available in the local ggplot environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [scale_x_date](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html#)

```
BT<-ggplot(Brown_Top_2013, aes(TIMESTAMP, Sum.of.WS_Avg))
BT+geom_point(col="royalBlue")+labs(x="Date", y="Mean Wind Speed (m/s)", title= "Daily Mean Wind Speed 2013")+scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels="%b %d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be the following one:

```
BT<-ggplot(Brown_Top_2013, aes(TIMESTAMP, Sum.of.WS_Avg))

BT+geom_point(col="royalBlue")+
   labs(x="Date", 
        y="Mean Wind Speed (m/s)", 
        title= "Daily Mean Wind Speed 2013")+ 
   scale_x_discrete(
        labels = seq.Date(as.Date("01/03/13","%m/%d/%y"), as.Date("12/27/13","%m/%d/%y"), by = "day"))
```

You have to change `breaks =` into `labels =`

Comment: If I understand the scale_x_discrete function correctly wouldn't this be trying to add a label for every day in the sequence of dates?

Comment: For my example I tried (with two dates) this works ... I didn´t know about the function `scale_x_date` , so your answer is much more elegant.